# Securing public endpoints for form submissions

Tags: .net, web-services, security, encryption, next.js

I have a next.js static website that has some forms such as contact, job applications, etc. Our backend is .NET 4.6. Since these forms are public, the API endpoints (Web services) basically have no authentication and anyone could start making requests using a tool such as Postman. How could I make these endpoints secure ? I thought of a few things I could do:

1. Encrypting the payloads of these requests and then decrypting them at the backend before processing it. The idea being if someone else can see the endpoint url, they still can't encrypt the data correctly and the endpoint would reject it. The problem arises that the key that frontend uses to encrypt the payload can be inspected using dev tools and then anyone could send correctly encrypted payloads.
2. At the backend, checking the request headers to make sure that referer or origin headers point to my website. The problem now is that there are tools that can help you imitate a successful request headers, meaning that someone could spoof a request with correct headers.

What would be best way to making those endpoints secure ? Is there a way I can restrict only my website to be able to request it ? Or is there a way to hide the encryption keys on client side ? Any other suggestions on how I could approach this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your API is public and the HTML that generates the payload is public, there is really no way to guarantee security.
However, you could make it harder by using the following steps

1. Request a token to send during form submit

   - When this token is requested, log the requestor's IP
   - Limit how many requests per IP can be allowed per hour (may be 5?)
2. Pass the token gotten from #1 in #2

   - When the form is submitted, verify that the token's requestor IP and current request IP Match
   - Check if there are other form submissions from the same IP in a given timeframe, if so, reject the request.

OR

You simply limit how many submissions per IP per hour are allowed.
While this will not STOP the attack, it will slow them down enough that they will move to easier targets.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ended up using encryption from the frontend such that every random IV/KEY combination cannot be reused. Also added rate limiting based on IP address, origin and host check as well. I guess security through obscurity is the way to go!